# The norm-squared of a moment map behaves like a Morse-Bott function

Tags: reference-request, sg.symplectic-geometry, morse-theory, moment-map

Let $G$ be a compact Lie group with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$. Let $<.,>$ denote a $G$-invariant inner product on $\mathfrak{g}$.

Let $(M,\omega)$ be a symplectic compact manifold endowed with a hamiltonian action of $G$, and let $\mu : M \longrightarrow \mathfrak{g}^*,$  be a moment map associated to this action. We fix a Riemannian metric $g$ on $M$.

I have read somewhere that every gradient flow line $\phi_x(t)$  of the norm-squared of the moment map $\mu$  begins and ends at a critical point, i.e $\lim_{t \rightarrow + \infty} \phi_t(x) $ and $\lim_{t \rightarrow - \infty} \phi_t(x) $ exist, and they are both critical points of the norm-squared of $\mu$.  but I couldn't find a proof of this fact anywhere, Hopefully someone can help.

(This is a follow-up question to This one: [The negative gradient flow of a Morse-Bott function on a compact manifold converges to a critical point?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/425477/the-negative-gradient-flow-of-a-morse-bott-function-on-a-compact-manifold-conver/429039#429039))

Comment: For a Hamiltonian $S^1$-action with Hamiltonian $H$, the square norm of the Hamiltonian may not be differentiable on the set $\{H=0\}$. For example when $\{H=0\}$ is disjoint from the fixed point set, then the square norm is not differentiable anywhere along it. So please clarify what you mean by critical points.

Comment: Also it may help if you could link to the place where you read it (if possible).

Comment: @NickL, the definition of critical points that I'm using is the following:  $\textbf{Def}$: we say  that $x \in M$ is a critical point of  $\vert \vert \mu \vert \vert ^2 $ if $d_x \vert \vert \mu \vert \vert ^2 =0$.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't remember where I have found the statement, But I do remember that this result was proven  in the paper Morse Theory of the moment map for representative of Quivers,  in the case where $M$ is a symplectic vector space.

Comment: Ah ok, that is usually referred to as the norm squared. Square norm usually means $||\mu||$. Indeed the norm squared is differentiable.

Comment: @NickL Thank you for correcting me! I'll edit my question.

Comment: This is proved in [Gradient flow of the norm squared of a moment map](https://www.e-periodica.ch/cntmng?pid=ens-001%3A2005%3A51%3A%3A14) by Eugene Lerman who attributes the proof to Duistermaat.

Comment: Thank you very much @GustavoGranja for pointing out this paper! Could you please rewrite your comment in the answer section, since it answered my question ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As requested I am submitting my comment as an answer.
The desired statement is proved in [Gradient flow of the norm squared of a moment map](https://www.e-periodica.ch/cntmng?pid=ens-001%3A2005%3A51%3A%3A14) by Eugene Lerman who attributes the proof to Duistermaat.